# What do I lose for losing a country?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

So I don't actually know what I lose when a country leaves the x-com project. I know I need a certain number of countries in x-com to survive and I know it prevents you from getting the continent bonus but what else do you lose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you lose a country due to a level 5 panic rating during council reports, the following things are no longer possible:

- Launch a satellite there to generate additional monthly income
- Complete any missions in that country
- Receive requests from that country to fulfill
- Secure that continent's bonus

So what you lose is the rewards for those activities and the (theoretical) income if you had a satellite there or were planning to launch one.

*Sidenote*:

*You can't rescue all countries, so I say go for those that are most important to you in terms of bonuses and income.*

Comment: I don't think they give monthly income without satellites in those countries, right?

Comment: Yes, they don't. But you can't get a satelite there anymore either. So you don't lose it right away, but you lose the ability to get that income. I updated the answer though.

Comment: Actually I did a playthrough on normal and beat with with all countries and all low panic :P. So thats why I wanted to know. I swapped to classic and well... wow it's hard.

Comment: Second Shykin on that. If you prioritize on satellites and minimize total global panic gain, it's also perfectly possible to save all countries on classic as well. Haven't managed it on impossible yet.

Comment: @Shykin Agreed.  "Sidenote" states that it is *impossible* to maintain support from all countries, but this is patently untrue, at least for Normal and Classic difficulties.  This should be revised if someone can confirm that it *is* possible to retain all countries on the hardest difficulty.

Comment: Keeping all countries on Impossible probably has more to do with random chance (i.e., where the abductions / terror missions target) than skill.